# vertical arrow with variable length

Tags: arrows

I wish to have a vertical arrows from the top of the page to the text, with the length of the arrow adjusted automaticall (like vertical fill).

Please advise.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{myarr}
\newcommand\VArrow[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{myarr}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (\themyarr);
  \draw[red,thick,->,#1] (\themyarr|-current page.north) -- (\themyarr);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

Some test text\VArrow and some more text goes here
\lipsum[2]
And now some more text to draw another arrow.\VArrow[blue,ultra thick,-latex]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument for `\VArrow` allows to pass options to the `\draw` command internally used to draw the arrow.

Since some calculations are internally performed. two or three runs are necessary for the code to stabilize.